# How to make Epic Games launcher open on my library?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

By default, when I open the Epic Games Launcher, it opens up the Epic Games Store.  This makes the launcher take longer to open, and I really don't want to look at the store, I want to open my library.  Is there a way to make it start on the library? (preferably by default)